# How to increase width of UIAlertController of type alert when added custom controller as "ContentViewController"?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am creating custom UIAlertController by adding my controller as

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
let lineController = SelectLineviewController.instantiate()
alert.setValue(lineController, forKey: "contentViewController")
```

Now it is taking the height of my controller but width remain constant i.e of default UIAlertController when presented as an alert. Is there any way to increase the width?

Comment: Using private API like this may lead to issues with Apple's review. I'm not certain. The doc for UIAlertController specifies "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified." You may want to look into an alternative

Comment: Give at look at the SDCAlertView framework.

Comment: Your best bet may be to use a third party library that provides functionality similar to UIAlertController and allows customisation.